# Self-extracting executable do not recognize an existing command in System32

Tags: windows, batch-file, uwfmgr

I'm developing a stack of Windows Batch scripts (`.bat`) which are subsequently converted to self-extracting executabled.

Currently I'm facing a really strange problem. I create this self-extracting executable, which, after extracting all the files, will launch the main wrapper, (`SETUP.bat`). The whole stack of the scripts gets running and everything goes right until some point.

One part of the stack has to commit some files with `UWFMGR`, and I have a loop for like this:

```bash
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F usebackq "tokens=*" %%F IN ("DIR /S /B /A-D") DO (
   uwfmgr file commit "%%F"
)
```

If I run the executable, the execution of the stack does not recognize the command `UWFMGR`

I stopped the execution of the script, and went with the same CMD, (which it's launched by the executable), to the `System32` folder to check if the `UWFMGR` is there. I did a `DIR "uwfmgr.exe"`, and it's not there. But if I go with another CMD (a new one) the command is there. I even went with a file explorer to verify it and it's completely there but somehow the CMD which it's being launched by the executable cannot recognize it.

I have tried to specify the whole path in the loop like this `"C:\Windows\System32\UWFMGR.exe"` and it doesn't even work.

The funny thing is that if run this script it works and commits all the files required.

```bash
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F usebackq "tokens=*" %%F IN ("DIR /S /B /A-D") DO (
   uwfmgr file commit "%%F"
)
```

Does anyone have any idea of why this is happening?

Check the output of the command and the errorlevel, it's `9009` (the file/command does not exist)
Do an `echo` to check the command I'm passing through the loop, the command is OK

I expect the executable to do the whole stack and commit the files but the executable does not recognize `UWFMGR` command. I use other commands in my stack and I didn't have any problem.

Comment: Is `UWFMGR.exe` part of the self-extracting executable? What is the program/method you are using to create your executable package? Why are you looking in/extracting to `System32`? Is the executable package being run elevated?

Comment: It's not. UWFMGR is on the system. I'm creating my executable with SFX (7zip). I'm not extracting anything on System32, I'm using in my script the UWFMGR which it's on System32. The executable is being ran as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

64-bit Windows has two system32 folders. Windows\system32 is the real folder used by 64-bit applications. 32-bit applications are automatically redirected to Windows\Syswow64 when they access system32. There is a backdoor you can use to access the real system32 folder.

You should use `if exist` and `set` to find and store a usable path:

```
@echo off
set app=%windir%\system32\UWFMGR.exe
set appalt=%windir%\sysnative\UWFMGR.exe
if not exist "%app%" if exist "%appalt%" set app=%appalt%
echo.I will use %app%
```

UWFMGR seems to be an optional feature and is probably not present by default on most machines.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it after finding out the exe was created as 32bits. I had to create as 64 bits in order to make it work. Now the executable is able to use the UWFMGR.

Thank you everyone for your answers and have a nice day.

I'm using this 7sfx module, just in case anyone's wondering: "7zsd_All_x64.sfx"